# In this sentence, to what does “gave rise to” refer?

Tags: reference

To what does “gave rise to” refer in this sentence? To “revolutionary temper” or to “a curious kind of partiality”?

In Lessing the revolutionary temper was associated with a curious kind of partiality which clung to concrete details with an exaggerated, almost pedantic carefulness, and **gave rise to** many misunderstandings. (Men in Dark Times, Hannah Arendt, p5)

Comment: Are you asking what the subject of the clauses are? The sentence is kind of clunky.

Comment: It's the same subject as _clung to_, and I agree the sentence is  clunky. But then, so is Lessing.

Comment: You seem to be having some issues understanding several parts of [the same sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562599/meaning-of-concrete-in-the-following-sentence) . What's up?

Comment: @Cascabel Yes. Do you have an answer for the question, or what?

Comment: Syntactically speaking, the syntax is potentially ***ambiguous***, so any answers can only be a matter of which interpretation seems ***most likely in context***. In short, it's Primarily Opinion-Based.

Comment: Following up on the comment by @Cascabel, it is unclear why **this** sentence needs special attention, given that it comes from a book that contains umpteen similarly complex sentences. In the absence of an explanation of what's so special about this sentence, it doesn't seem that discussing it at length will lead to any general insight into English language and usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping out the qualifying words may help:

... temper was associated with partiality which clung to details with carefulness, and gave rise to misunderstandings.

This suggests *the partiality clung to*... and *the partiality gave rise to*...

Had Arendt wished to imply the other meaning one might have expected:

... temper was associated with partiality which clung to details with carefulness, and **which** gave rise to misunderstandings.

The insertion of *which* as a parallel to the first *which* refers the following clause  to *temper*

The interpretation of the sentence therefore depends to some extent on the reader’s trust in Arendt’s precision of expression. A trusting soul, I favour the first.

Answer (score -1):

Simplified:

In Lessing, the revolutionary temper was [like this], and **the revolutionary temper in Lessing** [as described] gave rise to many misunderstandings.